# SUM of all Values in a field SQL

Tags: sql, count, sum

```
PenNo    PenDesc        NoOfPoints        TotalPoints
50194    Speeding       3
50111    No Seatbelt    2
50677    Ran Red Light  5
```

Hi, Im trying to total the NoOfPoints so that it will basically do 3+2+5 and output "10" under total points. Obviously i dont want to just type "3+2+5". I want to use the sum function. Can someone please help. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you actually tried to write SQL code?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? If it's just one total points column then all you need to do is select sum (noofpoints) from table.  It if your output needs one or more of the other source columns then it's a little more tricky as you have to aggregate over some group.  Also depending on which dbms you are using the syntax could be different for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT SUM(NoOfPoints) AS total_points FROM your_table_name
```

`SUM(X)` will sum all the values in column `X`

Use the keyword `AS` to give the sum result an alias.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this as your SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(NoOfPoints) FROM table_name
```

See this : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp